# Non-existent pages in Google Analytics (hostname correct)

Tags: google-analytics

I'm seeing non-existent pages in my analytics. I've done a fair amount of research and the most likely culprit is my tracking ID on another site, and that you can see this in analytics by showing the hostname.

Trouble is the hostname is correct.

an example; `/d/gps-tracker-cell-phone-f` There's a few dozen. The hostname shows my domain correctly.

The only exception is one that shows `mydomain.com.googleweblight.com` but only that one.

I've done a thorough analysis and I'm 97.6% sure this account has not been hacked.

Possible explanations?

Comment: What type of traffic is it? Direct, referral, organic? Could there be redirects to those pages somehow maybe an old domain are pointing to your website and you sort of inherit the url path. That could explain it..

Comment: If hostname is correct then the problem is not about having the tracking ID in a different domain.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I have figured it out.

I'm thinking it could be a 404/errorpage and you probably have tracking code on that page as well, so it will show up as a pageview in GA.

If you visit /d/gps-tracker-cell-phone-f and look at the realtime report in GA you can see if it shows up as a pageview and what the page looks like.

Why do you get these? I believe you've got external backlinks to your website with those paths, and since those pages don't exist your website will display a 404 and track it in GA.

Comment: This does seem like the most likely explanation. I can't see what use these links are, perhaps padding out a page for google results